# NSLocalisedString toggle between displaying key and translated text

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, string, nslocalizedstring

I have a app which is localised, i was wandering if theres a way to toggle between displaying the key and the translated text either while the app is running or through a debug build?

I want to run through my app and make sure there are no hardcoded strings

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but in the Xcode menu Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme… -> Run -> Options there is an option “Show non-localized strings” that will capitalize all strings in your UI that are not localized.

I hope this can solve your problem.